# "Private" visibility modifier - how to handle differences when converting C# to VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion, private, access-modifiers

**The Background**

I have converted the C# code below (found in TreeViewAdv file TreeColumn.cs) into VB.net code using the converter found at DeveloperFusion.com.

C#

```
using System;
//...(other using calls)

namespace Aga.Controls.Tree
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter)), DesignTimeVisible(false), ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class TreeColumn : Component
    {
        private class TreeColumnConverter : ComponentConverter
        {
            public TreeColumnConverter()
                : base(typeof(TreeColumn))
            {
            }

            public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
     }
    //…Some, I believe, unrelated code
}
```

VB

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
‘...(other Imports calls)

Namespace Aga.Controls.Tree

    <TypeConverter(GetType(TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter)), DesignTimeVisible(False), ToolboxItem(False)> _
    Public Class TreeColumn
        Inherits Component

        Private Class TreeColumnConverter
            Inherits ComponentConverter

            Public Sub New()
                MyBase.New(GetType(TreeColumn))
            End Sub

            Public Overrides Function GetPropertiesSupported(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
                Return False
            End Function
        End Class
    ‘...some, I believe, unrelated code
End Class
```

**The Problem**

Access to TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter in this line of the C# code is fine.
[TypeConverter(typeof(TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter)), DesignTimeVisible(false), ToolboxItem(false)]

However, VB.Net does not allow access to that member in the converted line:

The error description reads:  `Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'`.  However, in both cases TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter is declared Private.

**The Question(s)**

1.) The Why.  As this is a learning project for me, I would like to know WHY the scopes are acting differently among the two languages. This is the more important question among the 2 of them.

2.) The How.  What is the best way(s) to change the VB code to allow access of TreeColumnConverter to the identified line of code without opening up the scope to the point that it potentially creates naming confusions elsewhere?  I COULD just declare it Public, but I imagine there is a more correct approach to this.

**Things To Keep In Mind When Answering**

1.) I know that in VB.net Private members are not available external to the object in which they were declared. So telling me this will not be helpful and in my mind is not an answer.

Comment: Not that clear to me why this requires a giant answer.  Just change it from Private to Friend.  VB.NET is a friendly language.

Comment: @HansPassant You should post that as an answer, while you didn't give me the WHY, that is a valid HOW.  Jordao's answer is also a valid how.  If you can convince me your methodology is better I will give you the 'Accepted Answer'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, it looks like that the different compilers use different *philosophies* when dealing with nested private types. C# says its OK to access it from an attribute on the higher level type, VB.NET says it's not. Maybe those philosophies weren't even intentional.

Anyway, to fix it in VB.NET you could use the [`TypeConverterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.typeconverterattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor that uses a string instead of a `Type`, and put the fully-qualified nested type name as a string:

```
<TypeConverter("Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter"), DesignTimeVisible(False), ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class TreeColumn
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, after doing a little more research on the TypeConverter attribute it looks like a valid fix, but Hans Passant also makes a good point.  Are there advantages, in your mind, as to which would be better?  I will probably award answer on that discussion.

Comment: You'll change the accessibility of the nested type by making it `Friend` (`internal` in C#). It could be accessed by any other types in the same assembly.

Comment: True, and in fact that was my original concern, but I am cautious of using a constant there.  Is there any reason to believe that GetType(TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter) would every return a value other than "Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeColumn.TreeColumnConverter"? I would think not, but this is not my code and I don't understand all the methodologies quite yet (but I am trying to learn).

Comment: You could test the resulting code and check if it yields the expected result.

Comment: Well, yes, and I plan to do that, but it will take me a while as I am converting a very large project.  I was just wondering on a technical level if it is possible for those two arguments to diagree.  The only thing I can think of is if GetType method returns a Nothing/Null value.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I believe I see your problem.

It's the namespaces.

VB.NET Chains the Namespaces.

`Namespace Aga.Controls.Tree` in vb.net would actually be your project's default namespace concatenated with the namespace declared in the file.

It would actually be `Aga.Controls.Tree.Aga.Controls.Tree` so it likely just can't get to the scope it needs to be because it's pointing to the wrong namespace.

C#, you fully qualify namespaces... DevFusion's converter (same as the one used in SharpDevelop IDE) doesn't know this.

Comment: Am I sure? No... everyone's configuration of Visual Studio is a crap shoot.  I jump back and forth from VB.NET to C# project daily and when I have to convert one to the other (usually using the same dlls dev fusion uses) I always run into the namespaces concatenating themselves and throwing everything out of whack.  I've accessed nested private fields before without the need of using TypeConverter... so I'm at a loss truly.

Comment: @Steiner Where can you get the dlls dev fusion uses to convert?  I haven't seen any kind of link to it on their web site and I want to try my hand at writing a batch converter desktop application... If they don't already have one.

Comment: @Steiner ...and concerning your answer, I do not believe this is the case because I have removed the project's default (Root) namespace.  I was already running into that problem when trying to use Import statements earlier and removed it (which by the way fixed that issue), so I'm gonna say that's not it.

Comment: @ProtoNoob - Ok, I'm not entirely sure that they're the same; but these DLLs should aid you in your home-brew continuous integration.  Download the MSI for SharpDevelop and find the DLLs starting with `ICSharpCode.NRefactory` with 7-zip (you can open the msi in 7-zip and avoid the install). This page http://laputa.sharpdevelop.net/NRefactoryTutorialVideo.aspx also helped me do something similar to what it sounds like your needing them for.